# Pattern syntax using luacode

Tags: luatex, pattern, luacode

How can I find characters that are not curly braces? If I use this pattern `"[^}]"`  in `string.gsub` I get an error.

EDIT: This is the part of the code that doesn't work:

```
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
    function colorize ( s ) 
        s = string.gsub ( s , "K_%w" , "\\textcolor[HTML]{00804d}{%0}" )
        s = string.gsub ( s , "(A)([^}])" , "\\textcolor[HTML]{005ce6}{%1}%2"))         
        return s
    end
\end{luacode}

\newcommand{\colorizeOn}{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", colorize , "colorize" )}}
\newcommand{\colorizeOff}{\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback("process_input_buffer", "colorize" )}}
```

The first part of the script is ok (it substitutes all "K_" followed by an alphanumeric characters with the same thing but with a color code) while adding the second part (that should replace all "A" that are not followed by a "}" with "A" with its color code) it returns this errors:

```
Argument of \luacode@grab@lines has an extra }. s = string.gsub ( s , "(A)([^}
Paragraph ended before \luacode@grab@lines was complete. s = string.gsub ( s , "(A)([^}
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. s = string.gsub ( s , "(A)([^}
Missing \begin{document}. s = string.gsub ( s , "(A)([^}]
Missing \begin{document}. s = string.gsub ( s , "(A)([^}])" , "\\t
```

The main problem is the hat character in fact if I use this pattern `"[}]"` I get similar errors (the compiler expects to find a corresponding "{" before) and in my case I can easily fix that using this pattern instead `"[{}]"`. The problem is that I want the negation of this pattern that should be written as `"[^{}]"` that doesn't work.

EDIT 2: [this](http://codepad.org/dOxcOWgi) is what I expect.

Comment: Could you please add a complete example document of what your have tried and the exact error message you get?

Comment: Observe that `\textcolor[HTML]{005ce6}{A}BA}` (from the external file you provided a link to) features an unbalanced curly brace and thus cannot be handled properly by LaTeX.

Comment: It was just an example, in my case I want to find all "A" that ar not bold \textbf{A} so I check if they are not followed by a "}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use a `luacode*` environment instead of a `luacode` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
function colorize ( s ) 
    s = string.gsub ( s , "K_%w" , "\\textcolor{red}{%0}" )
    s = string.gsub ( s , "(A)([^{}])" , "\\textcolor{blue}{%1}%2")     
    return s
end
\end{luacode*}

\newcommand{\colorizeOn}{\directlua{ luatexbase.add_to_callback( 
   "process_input_buffer", colorize , "colorize" )}}
\newcommand{\colorizeOff}{\directlua{ luatexbase.remove_from_callback( 
   "process_input_buffer", "colorize" )}}

\begin{document}
$K_b$, Au, A{u}

\colorizeOn
$K_b$, Au, A{u}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks but I have another problem, if I write something like this `\textbf{A}$\,\to\,$\textbf{B}` inside a `\colorizeOn` - `\colorizeOff` environment (where even for B I use the same lua substitution rule as A) I get this strange output **A**005ce6AMSsymbols[HTML]005ce6A]005ce6AMSsymbols[HTML**B**. If I write the same line `\textbf{A}$\,\to\,$\textbf{B}` twice or more times only the first occurence is formatted as above while the others are formatted correctly (not modified since A and B are followed by a curly brace).

Comment: The lua rule I used for substitution is
`s = string.gsub ( s , "(A)([^{}])" , "\\textcolor[HTML]{005ce6}{%1}%2" )` and `s = string.gsub ( s , "(B)([^{}])" , "\\textcolor[HTML]{005ce6}{%1}%2" )`

Comment: Sorry, the strange output is **A**005ce6AMSsymbols[HTML]005ce6A]005ce6AMSsymbols[HTML]005ce6B] → **B**

Comment: @PrinceOfBorgo - I'm afraid I am unable to replicate the issue(s) you report. Incidentally, one should *never* write `\textbf{A}$\,\to\,$\textbf{B}`; it should be `$\mathbf{A}\to\mathbf{B}$`. (Note that the whole expression is a single "formula". Also, `\,` ("thinspace") isn't the correct amount of whitespace between math atoms of type math-ord and math-rel, respectively.) By the way, just employ a single `gsub` rule: `s = string.gsub ( s , "([AB])([^{}])" , "\\textcolor[HTML]{005ce6}{%1}%2")`.